# Evaluate the Integral: $\int\ e^{x}(1+e^x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate the Integral: $\int\ e^{x}(1+e^x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ dx$

$u=1+e^x$

$du=e^x\ dx$

$\int\ u^{\frac{1}{2}}\ du$

$u+c=1+e^x+c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int e^{x}(1+e^x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ dx$$
Using $u$-substitution, we have
$$ u=e^x+1$$
$$ du=e^x\ dx$$
So now
$$\int u^{\frac{1}{2}}\ du=\frac{u^{\frac12+1}}{\frac12+1}+C$$
$$=\frac{u^{\frac12+\frac22}}{\frac12+\frac22}+C=\frac{u^{\frac32}}{\frac32}+C$$
$$=\frac23 u^{\frac32}+C=\frac23 \left(e^x+1\right)^{\frac32}+C$$

Comment: Great work. Can you take a look at this problem and explain the integration part?  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1363397/evaluate-the-integral-int-frac1ex2ex-dx/1363410#1363410

Comment: @Cetshwayo Thanks. I've submitted my answer and I hope it helps you understand.

Answer (score 3):

Your change of variable is OK, $ u=e^x$, $du=e^xdx$, giving
$$\int e^{x}(1+e^x)^{\frac12}\ dx=\int (1+u)^{\frac12}\ du=\frac23(1+u)^{3/2}+C=\frac23(1+e^x)^{3/2}+C.$$

Comment: There's your upvote xD

Comment: Gummy bears it is $e^x$. I made an error in typing.

Comment: @Cetshwayo Because it was easier to have $e^xdx=du$ which was obtained with $u=e^x$. You may recall that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$ itself: $(e^x)'=e^x$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$$\int\ e^{3}(1+e^x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\ dx=$$
$$e^3\int\sqrt{e^x+1} dx=$$

(substitute $u=e^x$ and $du=e^xdx$):

$$e^3\int\frac{\sqrt{u+1}}{u} du=$$

(substitute $s=\sqrt{u+1}$ and $ds=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u+1}}du$):

$$2e^3\int\frac{s^2}{s^2-1} ds=$$
$$2e^3\int\left(-\frac{1}{2(s+1)}+\frac{1}{2(s-1)}+1\right)ds=$$
$$-e^3\int \frac{1}{s+1}ds+e^3\int \frac{1}{s-1}ds+2e^3\int1ds=$$

(substitute $p=s+1$ and $dp=ds$):

$$-e^3\int \frac{1}{p}dp+e^3\int \frac{1}{s-1}ds+2e^3\int1ds=$$
$$-e^3\ln(p)+e^3\int \frac{1}{s-1}ds+2e^3\int1ds=$$

(substitute $q=s-1$ and $dw=ds$):

$$-e^3\ln(p)+e^3\int \frac{1}{w}dw+2e^3\int1ds=$$
$$-e^3\ln(p)+e^3\ln(w)+2e^3\int1ds=$$
$$-e^3\ln(p)+e^3\ln(w)+2e^3s+C=$$
$$-e^3\ln(p)+e^3\ln(s-1)+2e^3s+C=$$
$$-e^3\ln(\sqrt{u+1}+1)+e^3\ln(\sqrt{u+1}-1)+2e^3\sqrt{u+1}+C=$$
$$-e^3\ln(\sqrt{e^x+1}+1)+e^3\ln(\sqrt{e^x+1}-1)+2e^3\sqrt{e^x+1}+C=$$

$$2e^3\left(\sqrt{e^x+1}-\tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{e^x+1}\right)\right)+C$$

Comment: Jan, det är inte $e^3$. Det är $e^x$ It isn't $e^3$ it is $e^x$

Comment: You solved a slightly more difficult problem.  But +1 anyway.  Well done!

Comment: @Dr.MV Thanks a lot!